# power bi-Error in df[j,(m+1):(m+s)] object of type 'closure' is not subsettable "

Tags: r

I am using below code in power BI (it is part of that) but getting

> Error in df[j,(m+1):(m+s)] object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Can anyone help me please?

```
f.con=matrix(ncol=N+1,nrow=m+s)
for (j in 1:N) {  
    f.rhs =c(rep(0,m),df[j(m+1):(m+s)])
    f.dir = c(rep("<=",m),rep(">=",s))
    f.obj = c(1,rep(0,N))   
for(i in 1:m){ 
    f.con[i,1:(N+1)]  = c(as.numeric(-df[ja,i]),df[,i])
}
```

Comment: I edited your code -- it looks like newlines were lost when you pasted it. But look at your loops -- did you mean nested loops (i within j) or sequential loops (j, then i)? In the first case you need a closing `}` at the end, in the second, it should be right before the second `for`.

Comment: As for the error message -- try `is(df)` or  `str(df)`. If you have not defined a data frame named `df`, chances are that the only `df` in your search path is `stats::df`, density function of the F-distribution, which is a function (= object of type 'closure'), so `df[i,j]` makes no sense.